# express/nodejs: best practice to create an object to be shared across modules and bound to the request lifetime

Tags: node.js, express, request

What's the best way to create an object, using a middleware, tight to the request lifetime that can be shared between modules?

Let's say you want to create dynamically an object based on the a req headers, one solution could be to create an object using a middleware and attach it to the req object.
Is it the common standard way to do that in express/node? 
Is there a way to have this object on its own, like a "service", and still in some way bound to the req scope and lifetime?

Comment: That is indeed the standard way.  For instance, a lot of the auth libraries will add a req.user object.  With the whole shared-memory thing that node.js does, having a separate object would get dangerous, as a global object would be overwritten with each new request, and anything else would just be another variable to pass around (otherwise it'd be gc-ed once the current scope was done).